# Error when connecting MySQL from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) to create a mvc application connecting to mysql and getting this error.

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code, Additional information: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

I followed everything from the tutorial apart from my mysql database is on godaddy rather than on azure. New database and new MVC Application in VS2013 .Net 4.5.1. EF 6.1.3 and MySQL.Data.Entity version is 6.9.8.

The error is on this line.

**context.Database.Create();**

I found some people got same problem but their solution isn't using SetInitializer like in this tutorial. I hope some one can point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
    {

        public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                // if database did not exist before - create it
                context.Database.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
                var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
                string.Format(
                  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'", "users"));

                // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
                if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
                {
                    context.Database.Delete();
                    context.Database.Create();
                }
            }
        }
    }

 public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public MySqlHistoryContext(
              DbConnection existingConnection,
              string defaultSchema)
        : base(existingConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class MySqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MySqlConfiguration()
    {
        SetHistoryContext(
        "MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new      MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
        }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in three ways:

Adding the DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the context class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

Calling `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration())` at the application startup
Set the DbConfiguration type in the configuration file:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. on the context class, do you mean ApplicationDbContext class in IdentityModels.cs? I have tried that and i got similar error again but this time saying 767 bytes instead of 1000 bytes.

Comment: I have tried calling the second option in Global.asax and give me this error when calling SetInitializer method. An instance of 'MySqlEFConfiguration' was set but this type was not discovered in the same assembly as the 'ApplicationDbContext' context.

Comment: third option gives me the same error as the first option. Any suggestion Eminem?